# How to constrain type to types with index?

Tags: dictionary, go, generics, indexing, slice

I decided to dive into Go since 1.18 introduced generics. I want to implement an algorithm that only accepts sequential types — arrays, slice, maps, strings, but I'm not able to crack how.

Is there a method that can be targeted involving indexability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a constraint with a union, however the only **meaningful** one you can have is:

```
type Indexable interface {
    ~[]byte | ~string
}

func GetAt[T Indexable](v T, i int) byte {
    return v[i]
}
```

And that's all, for the time being. Why?

1. The operations allowed on types with union constraint are only those allowed for all types in the constraint type set.
2. To allow indexing, the types in the union must have equal key type and equal element type.
3. The type parameter proposal suggests that `map[int]T` could be used in a union with `[]T`, however this has been disallowed. The specs now mention this in [Index expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Index_expressions): *"If there is a map type in the type set of P, all types in that type set must be map types, and the respective key types must be all identical"*.
4. For arrays, the length is part of the type, so a union would have to specify all possible lengths you want to handle, e.g. `[1]T | [2]T` etc. Quite impractical, and prone to out-of-bounds issues (There's a [proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44253) to improve this).

So the only union with diverse types that supports indexing appears to be `[]byte | string` (possibly approximated `~`). Since `byte` is an alias of `uint8`, you can also instantiate with `[]uint8`.

Other than that, there's no other way to define a constraint that supports indexing on *all* possible indexable types.

**NOTE** that `[]byte | string` supports indexing **but not range**, because this union [doesn't have a core type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516746/how-to-iterate-over-a-union-of-slices-passed-in-a-generic-function-t-has-no-co/71516910#71516910).

Playground: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/uatvtMo_mrZ