# How to iterate over a union of slices passed in a generic function? (T has no core type)

Tags: go, generics

I am testing out generics in go 1.18 and took a look at this [example](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics#declare_type_constraint).
I would like to recreate that example but instead be able to pass in a slice of int or slice of float instead, and in the function I'll just sum up everything in the slice.

This is when I ran into some issues just iterating the slice. This is what I tried:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// NumberSlice constraint
type NumberSlice interface {
    []int64 | []float64
}

func add[N NumberSlice](n N) {
    // want: to range over n and print value of v 
    for _, v := range n {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}

func main() {
    ints := []int64{1, 2}
    add(ints)
}
```

I got the error:

> cannot range over n (variable of type N constrained by NumberSlice) (N has no core type)

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [core type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Core_types), for an interface (including an interface constraint) is defined as follows:

> An interface T has a core type if one of the following conditions is
> satisfied:
>
> - There is **a single type `U` which is the underlying type of all types in the type set of T**
> - or the type set of T contains only channel types with identical element type E, and all directional channels have the same direction.

Your interface constraint has no core type, because it has **two** underlying types: `[]int64` and `[]float64`.

Therefore you can't use it where a core type is required. Notably `range` and `make`.

You can change the interface to require the base types, and then specify the slice in the function signature:

```
// still no core type...
type Number interface {
    int64 | float64
}

// ...but the argument will be instantiated with either int64 or float64
func add[N Number](n []N) {
    for _, v := range n {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

This also works, but it's way more verbose:

```
type NumberSlice[N int64 | float64] interface {
    // one core type []N
    ~[]N
}

func add[S NumberSlice[N], N int64 | float64](n S) {
    for _, v := range n {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could something like this work for you?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type NumberOrFloat interface {
    int64 | float64
}

func add[N NumberOrFloat](n []N) {
    for _, v := range n {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}

func main() {
    ints := []int64{1, 2}
    add(ints)
}
```

The difference here is that you define type constraints on array elements (not on array types): []N

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).