# invalid operation: cannot index T when modeling slices of arbitrary dimensions

Tags: go, generics

I am try to do a matrix subtraction with unknow size of matrix. here is the code:

```
type ArrayLike interface {
    []interface{} | [][]interface{} | [][][]interface{} | [][][][]interface{}
}

func subMatrix[T ArrayLike](A, B T, shape []int) interface{} {

    dim := shape[0]
    if len(shape) == 1 {
        retObj := make([]interface{}, dim)
        for i := 0; i < dim; i++ {
            Av := A[i].(float64)
            Bv := B[i].(float64)
            retObj[i] = Av - Bv
        }
        return retObj
    } else {
        retObj := make([]interface{}, dim)
        for i := 0; i < dim; i++ {
            retObj[i] = subMatrix(Av[i], Bv[i], shape[1:])
        }
        return retObj
    }
}
```

It complains about

> invalid operation: cannot index A (variable of type T constrained by []interface{}|[][]interface{}|[][][]interface{}|[][][][]interface{})compilerNonIndexableOperand

Does anyone know how to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, not with generics and not with `interface{}`/`any` alone. The main issue is that you can't statically model slices with arbitrary dimensions — i.e. arbitrary types. Let's go in order:

The error message you got is because you can't index a type parameter with a union constraint like that. Specs, [Index expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Index_expressions):

> For a of type parameter type P:
>
> - [...]
> - The element types of all types in P's type set must be
>   identical. [...]

The element types of `ArrayLike`'s type set are *not* identical. The element type of `[]interface{}` is `interface{}`, the one of `[][]interface{}` is `[]interface{}` and so on.

There is a placebo solution to the indexing error, [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516746/how-to-iterate-over-a-union-of-slices-passed-in-a-generic-function-t-has-no-co), basically it involves changing the type of the arguments `A` and `B` to a slice `[]T`. Then you can index `A[i]` and `B[i]`.

**However this isn't enough.** At this point, there's no way to pass correct arguments to the recursive call. The type of the expression `A[i]` is now `T`, but `subMatrix` wants `[]T`.

Even dropping type parameters and declaring the args `A` and `B` as `any` doesn't work, because on the recursive call you still want to index them. In order to index, you have to assert `any` to something that's indexable, but *what* would that be? **At each recursion the types would have one less dimension**, so a statically typed assertion would eventually panic.

The only way to solve this is (probably?) with reflection, but honestly I don't see a practical utility to do that.

You can, and should, write a generic function for each matrix dimension:

```
import "golang.org/x/exp/constraints"

type Number interface {
    constraints.Integer | constraints.Float
}

func Sub2DMatrix[T Number](a, b [][]T) {
    for i := range a {
        for j := range a[i] {
            a[i][j] -= b[i][j]
        }
    }
}
```